# Excel VBA: Single column: Find text, copy text and other rows' text below, transpose to cols on 2nd tab

Tags: excel, vba

I have a very specific VBA need: Creating a table of data from a single column of data.

Find text in a column, copy/paste, then dropping x rows down, copy/paste, then dropping x rows down, copy/paste, etc. I have one column of data A:A

- Sheet1: Find text "MyText", copy "MyText", Paste to Sheet2, A2
- Sheet1: from "MyText", drop 5 rows, copy text, paste into Sheet2, B2
- Sheet1: from "MyText", drop 8 rows, copy text, paste into Sheet2, C2
- Sheet1: from "MyText", drop 16 rows, copy text, paste into Sheet2, D2

Then loop to find the next "MyText" and paste into A3, and so on.

Thanks!
Charlie E

Comment: Please read the site rules, particularly: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Start by using the macro recorder.  Developer Tab --> Record Macro

Comment: Is "MyText" part of the cell string, or whole string?

Comment: The whole string @FaneDuru

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the next code, please:

```
Sub CopyMyTextReferences()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, sh2 As Worksheet, i As Long, MyText As String, rngTxt As Range
  Dim rng As Range, rng2 As Range, lastRow As Long, lastR As Long, strFirstAddr As String
  
  Set sh = ActiveSheet           'use here your sheet to copy from
  Set sh2 = Worksheets("Sheet2") 'use here your sheet where to copy
  MyText = "testStr" 'use here your string to be searched
  
  lastRow = sh.Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
  Set rng = sh.Range("A2:A" & lastRow)
  
  Set rngTxt = rng.Find(MyText, sh.Range("A2"), xlValues, xlWhole)
  If Not rngTxt Is Nothing Then
     strFirstAddr = rngTxt.Address
     
     Do
        lastR = sh2.Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        Set rng2 = sh2.Range("A" & lastR)
        With rng2
          .Value = rngTxt.Offset(4).Value
          .Offset(1).Value = rngTxt.Offset(5).Value
          .Offset(2).Value = rngTxt.Offset(8).Value
          .Offset(3).Value = rngTxt.Offset(16).Value
          '.Offset(4).Value = rngTxt.Offset(xx).Value
        End With
        Set rngTxt = rng.FindNext(After:=rngTxt)
     Loop Until rngTxt.Address = strFirstAddr
  Else
     MsgBox MyText & " could not be found...": Exit Sub
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a great start for me!
Two things:
- I would like to start copying the text at MyText +4, not at MyText
- If I want to continue copying, do I need a loop or do I add lines with every offset value from the MyText?  

.Offset(6).Value = rngTxt.Offset(14).Value
.Offset(6).Value = rngTxt.Offset(19).Value..... etc.?

Comment: Now I am driving. I will adapt the code when being at home...

Comment: @ChasEpes: Updated the code to start copying from the forth row down. In order to copy other ranges with reference to `rngText` no need to loop. You only fill down incrementing with 1 the cell where to paste and the appropriate offset for the cell to be copied. I added a commented line like example.